# Blender Geometry Nodes: Render Instance Id Next to Instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

**How do I render a string curve containing the instance ID next to all instances of an "Instance on Points" node**

Concrete example:

I want to render X keyboard keys and render their respective key number ( or instance Id ) above them.

I wasnt yet able to achieve this using the Tutorials I've found ( I'm a blender noob ).
But still I though that asking this question here might help another noob to understand how the instance ID's of "Instances on Points" can be used.
Here is what I've got so far:

[image: blender key instances]

Now I want some way to get the current instance ID and use it as value for the curve that is rendered above the instance.

Comment: if i where u i would tell us what your end result is instead of asking for a "mid term goal" because there might be a better idea than u have in mind now

Comment: The desired end result is in the title "Render Instance Id Next to Instances":

Or more verbose:
How do I render a string curve containing the instance ID next to all instances of an "Instances on Points" node

Comment: Should I clarify more? Please give me a hint what is still unclear.

Comment: Maybe an Example:

Above I have a line with 100 points, now I instance a cube on every point.
I expect that the "Instance on Points" node has an ID for the instances, i.e.: instance 1 : ID1, instance 2: ID2 ... instance 100 ID: 100. This ID I want to render next to the instance as text.

Comment: Yeah sure this was marked as duplicate *BUT*:

The duplicates answers aren't really explaining how to solve the problem rather they offer magical solutions without explanation, also I wonder if a feature like: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/repeat_zone.html
might also offer a novel solution to this issue.

I don't think the other question is up to-date or exhaustive.